# Backpack V4 modifying field before store

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

In 3.6 version of backpack I can change an attribute value before storing it.
I have this code

```
If ($request->description == "") {
    $request->description="User has not entered any description";
}
$redirect_location = parent::storeCrud($request);
```

What can I do to get the same in V4? I'm reading this [guide](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.0/upgrade-guide#crudcontrollers) but I can't make it to work.
This is what I'm trying in V4

```
public function store(PedidoRequest $request)
{
    Log::debug('testing...');



    If ($request->description == "") {
       $request->description="User has not entered any description";
    }

    $redirect_location = $this->traitStore();
    return $redirect_location;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Request object in Laravel, `Illuminate\Http\Request`, doesn't have the ability to set the inputs via the properties like that, no `__set` method (`$request->description = '...'` does not set an input named `description`). You would have to merge the inputs into the request or use the array syntax to do that:

```
$request->merge(['description' => '...']);
// or
$request['description'] = '...';
```

But since backpack seems to have abstracted things apparently you aren't controlling anything in your controller methods you could try this:

```
$this->crud->request->request->add(['description'=> '...']);
```

Potentially:

```
$this->request->merge(['description' => '...']);
```

That would be assuming some trait the Controller uses is using the `Fields` trait.

Comment: I have tried both methods you have shown, but none of them are working for me...

Comment: Thank you! That worked!! You are right. I think 3.6 version was easier.